# How can I do texture mapping with a pyramid in webgl?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, texture-mapping

I have to make textured pyramid in WebGL for an assignment.
I searched and pasted some codes and fixed several errors, but it doesn't work properly.
Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?
There isn't certain error, and screen only shows this :

[image]

and the texture image is this :

[image]

and this is my code :

```js
var gl = null,
  canvas = null,
  glProgram = null,
  fragmentShader = null,
  vertexShader = null;

var coordinateArray = [],
  triangleVerticeColors = [],
  verticesArray = [],
  verticesIndexArray = [],
  triangleTexCoords = [];

var vertexPositionAttribute = null,
  trianglesVerticeBuffer = null,
  vertexColorAttribute = null,
  trianglesColorBuffer = null,
  triangleVerticesIndexBuffer = null,
  vertexTexCoordAttribute = null,
  trianglesTexCoordBuffer = null;



var P = mat4.create(),
  V = mat4.create(),
  M = mat4.create(),
  VM = mat4.create(),
  PVM = mat4.create();

var uPVMMatrix;

var texture;
var textureImage = null;

initWebGL();

function initWebGL() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
  try {
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") ||
      canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
  } catch (e) {}
  if (gl) {
    setupWebGL();
    initShaders();
    loadTexture();
    setupBuffers();

    //getMatrixUniforms();
    //setMatrixUniforms();
    //animationLoop();
    drawScene();
  } else {
    alert("Error: Your browser does not appear to" + "support WebGL.");
  }
}

function animationLoop() {
  var R = mat4.create();
  var angle = 0;
  var i = 0;

  var loop = function() {
    angle = performance.now() / 1000 / 6 * 2 * Math.PI;
    i++;
    mat4.rotate(PVM, R, angle, [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uPVMMatrix, false, PVM);

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawScene();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function setupWebGL() {
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.frontFace(gl.CW);
  gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



  console.log(P);
  console.log(V);
  console.log(M);

  //  mat4.identity(M);
  mat4.lookAt(V, [5, 0, -5], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
  mat4.perspective(P, glMatrix.toRadian(45), canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 1000.0);

  mat4.multiply(VM, V, M);
  mat4.multiply(PVM, P, VM);


}

function initShaders() {
  var fs_source = document.getElementById('shader-fs').innerHTML,
    vs_source = document.getElementById('shader-vs').innerHTML;

  vertexShader = makeShader(vs_source, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  fragmentShader = makeShader(fs_source, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  glProgram = gl.createProgram();

  gl.attachShader(glProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(glProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(glProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(glProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Unable to initialize the shader program.");
  }

  gl.useProgram(glProgram);

  uPVMMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, "uPVMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uPVMMatrix, false, PVM);

}



function loadTexture() {
  textureImage = document.getElementById("moon");
  setupTexture();
}

function setupTexture() {
  texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImage);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  glProgram.sampleUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, "uSampler");
  gl.uniform1i(glProgram.sampleUniform, 0);

  if (!gl.isTexture(texture)) {
    console.log("Error : Texture is invalid");
  }
}

function makeShader(src, type) {
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);

  gl.shaderSource(shader, src);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert("Error compiling shader: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  }
  return shader;
}

function setupBuffers() {
  // n-sides polygon
  var n = 6;
  var radius = 1;
  var angle = (Math.PI * 2) / n;
  var xCoordinate = 0;
  var yCoordinate = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    var a = angle * i;
    var xNewCoordinate = xCoordinate + radius * Math.cos(a);
    var yNewCoordinate = yCoordinate + radius * Math.sin(a);
    var zNewCoordinate = 0;
    coordinateArray.push(xNewCoordinate);
    coordinateArray.push(yNewCoordinate);
    coordinateArray.push(zNewCoordinate);

  }

  verticesArray = [

    //Bottom Face
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

    //Front Face
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 1.0, -0.5,

    //Right Face
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.5, 1.0, -0.5,

    //Back Face
    1.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.5, 1.0, -0.5,

    //Left Face
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 1.0, -0.5,
  ];

  trianglesVerticeBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesVerticeBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verticesArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  verticesIndexArray = [
    0, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8,
    9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17,
  ];

  triangleVerticesIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  triangleVerticesIndexBuffer.number_vertext_points = verticesIndexArray.length;
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVerticesIndexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(verticesIndexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  triangleTexCoords = [
    0.5000, 0.1910,
    0.1910, 0.5000,
    0.5000, 0.8090,
    0.5000, 0.1910,
    0.5000, 0.8090,
    0.8090, 0.5000,

    0.5000, 0.1910,
    0.8090, 0.5000,
    1.0000, 0.0000,

    0.8090, 0.5000,
    0.5000, 0.8090,
    1.0000, 1.0000,

    0.5000, 0.8090,
    0.1910, 0.5000,
    0.0000, 1.0000,

    0.1910, 0.5000,
    0.5000, 0.1910,
    0.0000, 0.0000,
  ];

  trianglesTexCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesTexCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleTexCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  triangleVerticeColors = [
    // Bottom quad
    0.470, 0.796, 0.886,
    0.470, 0.796, 0.886,
    0.470, 0.796, 0.886,
    0.470, 0.796, 0.886,
    0.470, 0.796, 0.886,
    0.470, 0.796, 0.886,

    // Back triangle
    0.772, 0.470, 0.886,
    0.772, 0.470, 0.886,
    0.772, 0.470, 0.886,

    // Left triangle
    0.886, 0.552, 0.470,
    0.886, 0.552, 0.470,
    0.886, 0.552, 0.470,

    // Front triangle
    0.886, 0.882, 0.470,
    0.886, 0.882, 0.470,
    0.886, 0.882, 0.470,

    // Right triangle
    0.470, 0.886, 0.505,
    0.470, 0.886, 0.505,
    0.470, 0.886, 0.505,
  ];

  trianglesColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesColorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVerticeColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

// GPU

function getMatrixUniforms() {

  glProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, "uMVMatrix");
  glProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, "uPMatrix");
  glProgram.vMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(glProgram, "uVMatrix");

}

// GPU

function setMatrixUniforms() {

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, M);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, P);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(glProgram.vMatrixUniform, false, V);

}

function drawScene() {
  vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(glProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesVerticeBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  vertexTexCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(glProgram, "aVertexTextureCoord");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexTexCoordAttribute);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesTexCoordBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexTexCoordAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  /*vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(glProgram, "aVertexColor");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorAttribute);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, trianglesColorBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexColorAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  */


  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, triangleVerticesIndexBuffer.number_vertext_points, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

canvas {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
  attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
  attribute vec2 aVertexTextureCoord;

  varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
  varying vec4 vColor;
  /*

  Couting On GPU

  // Model matrix
  uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
  // Projection matrix
  uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
  // View matrix
  uniform mat4 uVMatrix;

  */

  uniform mat4 uPVMatrix;

  void main(void) {
  vColor = aVertexColor;
  gl_Position = uPVMatrix * aVertexPosition;
  vTextureCoord = aVertexTextureCoord;
  //   gl_Position = uPMatrix * uVMatrix * uMVMatrix * aVertexPosition;
  }
</script>
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec4 vColor;
  varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
  uniform sampler2D uSampler;
  void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
  }
</script>

<canvas id="my-canvas" width="800" height="600">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas element.
</canvas>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/oLiU4fm.jpg" crossOrigin="anonymous" id="moon"/>
```